# How do I create a reusable component based on a static component using Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, headless-ui

I have recently started with Vue 3 and Headless UI.

I have created a `ListBox` component which is used in `App.vue` to show a list of `People` and is working as intended.
I am looking to turn it into a reusable component for showing lists of both `People` and `Countries`.

How can I change my component to be dynamic for both types?

**ListBox.vue**

```
<template>

    <Listbox v-model="selectedPerson">

        <ListboxButton class=" bg-white shadow-sm border-gray-500 border-2 shadow-gray-200 font-bold p-4 text-left rounded-md">
            {{ selectedPerson.name }}
        </ListboxButton>

        <ListboxOptions class="mt-2">

            <ListboxOption
                as="template" v-slot="{ active }"
                v-for="person in people" :key="person"
                :value="person">
                <li :class="{
                    'bg-blue-500 text-white p-6': active,
                    'bg-white shadow-lg p-6 text-black ': !active
                }">
                    {{ person.name }}
                </li>
            </ListboxOption>

        </ListboxOptions>

    </Listbox>

</template>

<script setup>
    import { ref } from 'vue'
    import {
        Listbox,
        ListboxLabel,
        ListboxButton,
        ListboxOptions,
        ListboxOption,
    } from '@headlessui/vue'

    const people = [
        { id: 1, name: 'Durward Reynolds' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Kenton Towne' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Therese Wunsch' },
        { id: 4, name: 'Benedict Kessler' },
        { id: 5, name: 'Katelyn Rohan' },
    ]
    const selectedPerson = ref(people[0])
</script>
```

**App.vue:**

```
<template>
    <ListBox />
</template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to accept both the list of items to show and the currently selected item or list index as props on the component.
The below is an example, coded on-the-fly and not tested, but should give you a clear idea of what to try and how to proceed.

Also I'd rename the component to avoid confusion with the `Listbox` component you're using from Headless UI.

**App.vue**

```
<template>
   <ItemList :items='people' :selected-index='0' />
   <ItemList :items='countries' :selected-index='0' />
</template>

<script>
const people = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Durward Reynolds' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Kenton Towne' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Therese Wunsch' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Benedict Kessler' },
    { id: 5, name: 'Katelyn Rohan' },
]
const countries = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Italy' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Switzerland' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Austria' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Germany' },
]
</script>
```

**ItemList.vue**

```
<template>
    <Listbox v-model="selectedItem">
        <ListboxButton class=" bg-white shadow-sm border-gray-500 border-2 shadow-gray-200 font-bold p-4 text-left rounded-md">
            {{ selectedItem.name }}
        </ListboxButton>

        <ListboxOptions class="mt-2">
            <ListboxOption
                as="template" v-slot="{ active }"
                v-for="item in items" :key="item.id"
                :value="item">
                <li :class="{
                    'bg-blue-500 text-white p-6': active,
                    'bg-white shadow-lg p-6 text-black ': !active
                }">
                    {{ item.name }}
                </li>
            </ListboxOption>
        </ListboxOptions>
    </Listbox>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
import {
    Listbox,
    ListboxLabel,
    ListboxButton,
    ListboxOptions,
    ListboxOption,
} from '@headlessui/vue'

const props = defineProps({
    items: Array,
    selectedIndex: Number,
})

const selectedItem = ref(null)

onMounted(() => {
    if(items && selectedIndex >= 0 && selectedIndex < items.length) {
        selectedItem.value = items[selectedIndex]
    }
})
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, under console it shows, items is not defined

Comment: Is that in relation to the use in the template or when assigning the `selectedItem`?

Comment: yes, at ref(items[selectedIndex])

Comment: Then the assignment probably needs to be done in a life cycle hook to use props properly. You can write out the need for the `ref` by changing `selectedItem` to `items[selectedIndex]` in the template, but it's not entirely clear if you're passing the chosen item back from your component and if that could be changed to just passing the index.

Comment: I've updated my answer to try and wrap the `ref` assignment in an early life cycle hook to await the prop availability, so it might work for you now.

Comment: same error, in your last answer i changed const selectedItem=ref([1]) and it was working. was it correect way?

Comment: The initialisation of the `ref` for `selectedItem` just assigns the default value, so if the `Listbox` component works with `[1]` being selected you can probably just pass `selectedIndex` directly into the `v-model`.
I've cleaned the dual `ref` setup and added a guard. Any further troubles with `ref` and `v-model` is out of scope for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You almost did what you want, only thing you need is `props`.
`people` and `countries` are instance of your child component `DataTable.vue` and you want to use them in a parent component `App.vue`.

DataTable.vue :

```
<template>
 <div id='data-table'> 
   {{table}}
 </div>
</template>
 
<script>
export default {
  .
  .
  .
 props: ['table']
}
</script>
```

App.vue:

```
<template>
   <data-table table='people' />
   <data-table table='countries' />
</template>
```

And also you have to Define the tables in outside the child component and then pass to the child , the better way to this is using `state management` like [`vuex`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/)